# Can't determine which FROM clause to join from

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm developing a Flask web app where a user creates multiple businesses to match with other's businesses.

And upon creating the business, you will need to provide the SEEKING and OFFERING of the business. My goal is to match the SEEKING of the current user's company with the OFFERING of other businesses from other users.

So I tried first to print the output through Command Line to test, and so far I was able to print the other Company's details of the matched OFFERING. And now I want to display which of the current user's companies was being matched with, and I came across this error.

I have tried the code below, and got this error.

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't determine which FROM clause to join from, there are multiple FROMS which can join to this entity. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explicit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.

```
    # Get the Seeking data for the user's company
    user_company = db.session.query(Company).join(User).filter(User.id == current_user.id).first()
    user_seeking = user_company.seeking
    
    # Get the Offering data from other companies that match the user's Seeking criteria
    matching_offerings = db.session.query(Offering, Company, Seeking).join(Company).join(Seeking).filter(
        Company.user_id != current_user.id,  # Exclude current user's company
        Offering.category.in_([seek.category for seek in user_seeking]),
        Offering.category == Seeking.category
    ).all()
    
    # Group offerings by Company
    offerings_by_company = {}
    for offering, company1, matched_seeking in matching_offerings:
        if company1.business_name not in offerings_by_company:
            offerings_by_company[company1.business_name] = {
                'company_details': company1,
                'matched_seekings': [],
                'offerings': []
            }
        offerings_by_company[company1.business_name]['offerings'].append(offering)
        offerings_by_company[company1.business_name]['matched_seekings'].append(matched_seeking)
    
    # Print the companies, their matching offerings, and matched seeking details
    print("Matching Companies, Offerings, and Matched Seeking Details:")
    for business_name, data in offerings_by_company.items():
        print(f"Business Name: {business_name}")
        print("Company Details:")
        print(f"  Business Name: {data['company_details'].business_name}")
        print(f"  Business Email: {data['company_details'].business_email}")
        print(f"  Business Address: {data['company_details'].business_address}")
        print("Offerings:")
        for offering in data['offerings']:
            print(f"  Category: {offering.category}")
        print("Matched Seeking Details:")
        for matched_seeking in data['matched_seekings']:
            print(f"  Seeking ID: {matched_seeking.id}")
            print(f"  Category: {matched_seeking.category}")
            print(f"  Seeking Company Name: {matched_seeking.company.business_name}")
            print(f"  Seeking Company Email: {matched_seeking.company.business_email}")
            print(f"  Seeking Company Address: {matched_seeking.company.business_address}")
        print("-----")
```

Below here is the database model of the code.

```
class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # logo_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    logo_data = db.Column(db.db.String(255))
    business_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    business_email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    business_address = db.Column(db.String(300))
    business_phone = db.Column(db.String(80))
    business_desc = db.Column(db.String(2000))
    # Foreign Keys
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    seeking = db.relationship('Seeking', back_populates='company')
    offering = db.relationship('Offering', back_populates='company')


class Seeking(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    business_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    category = db.Column(db.String(80))
    # Foreign Keys
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
    company = db.relationship('Company', back_populates='seeking')

class Offering(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    business_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    category = db.Column(db.String(80))
    # Foreign Keys
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
    company = db.relationship('Company', back_populates='offering')


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    # username = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    companies = db.relationship('Company')
```